# addclass to first-level elements only

Tags: jquery, html-table, n-tier-architecture

HTML:

```
<table id="table-1">
  <tr>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>content</td>
        <tr>
      </table>   
    </td>

    <td>Content</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to addclass 'td-1' to ONLY first-level TD's of #table-1 and not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table-1 td:first').addClass('td-1');
```

check: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first

This will add the class only to first td in first tr,

Sinan.

**EDIT:**

```
`$('#table-1>tbody>tr>td').addClass('td-1');`
```

it should be as above for all first level td items.

Comment: That'd pick ONLY the first TD, not all TDs of the same level, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the selector `#table-1>tbody>tr>td` to only get the first level cells:

```
$('#table-1>tbody>tr>td').addClass('td-1');
```

Comment: Note: the > selector means direct child (A>B matches B's that are son of A, "A B" matches a B that has a parent A anywhere above it :D

Comment: The browser adds an implicit tbody element around the table rows. I corrected the selector.